# Completely lost on this ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is from Carmen Chicone's book on page 5, and I don't even know where to start. I haven't done differential equations in a while so this is really a problem for me. I'll accept any hints or suggestions.

Find the general solution of the differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{(y+2)e^y - 2x}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hint:*** It is a linear equation $$\frac{1}{x'}=\frac{y}{(y+2)e^y - 2x}
\\ x'=\frac{(y+2)e^y - 2x}{y}\\ x'+\frac{ 2}{y}x=(1+\frac{2 }{y})e^y$$ The factor is
$$\mu=e^{\int\frac{2}{y}} =y^2$$ Then the solution is
$$x=\frac{1}{y^2}[\int y^2(1+\frac{2 }{y})e^ydy+c]$$

Comment: Yes the final answer was very satisfying! Thank you